# Matplotlib PDF export uses wrong font

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, cairo

I want to generate high-quality diagrams for a presentation. I’m using Python’s matplotlib to generate the graphics. Unfortunately, the PDF export seems to ignore my font settings.

I tried setting the font both by passing a `FontProperties` object to the text drawing functions and by setting the option globally. For the record, here is a MWE to reproduce the problem:

```
import scipy
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('cairo')
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

data = scipy.arange(5)

for font in ['Helvetica', 'Gill Sans']:
    fig = pylab.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.bar(data, data)
    ax.set_xticks(data)
    ax.set_xticklabels(data, fontproperties = fm.FontProperties(family = font))
    pylab.savefig('foo-%s.pdf' % font)
```

In both cases, the produced output is identical and uses Helvetica (and yes, I *do* have both fonts installed).

Just to be sure, the following doesn’t help either:

```
matplotlib.rc('font', family = 'Gill Sans')
```

Finally, if I replace the backend, instead using the native viewer:

```
matplotlib.use('MacOSX')
```

I *do* get the correct font displayed – but only in the viewer GUI. The PDF output is once again wrong.

To be sure – I *can* set other fonts – but only other classes of font families: I can set `serif` fonts or `fantasy` or `monospace`. But all sans-serif fonts seem to default to Helvetica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "family" argument and the corresponding rc parameter <strike>are not meant to specify the name of the font</strike> can actually be used this way. There's an (arguably baroque) CSS-like font selection system that helps the same script work on different computers, selecting the closest font available. The usually recommended way to use e.g. Gill Sans is to add it to the front of the value of the rc parameter font.sans-serif (see [sample rc file](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/customizing.html#matplotlibrc-sample)), and then set font.family to sans-serif.

This can be annoying if the font manager decides for some obscure reason that Gill Sans is not the closest match to your specification. A way to bypass the font selection logic is to use `FontProperties(fname='/path/to/font.ttf')` ([docstring](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties)).

In your case, I suspect that the MacOSX backend uses fonts via the operating system's mechanisms and so automatically supports all kinds of fonts, but the pdf backend has its own font support code that doesn't support your version of Gill Sans.

Comment: You said, “The "family" argument [is] not meant to specify the name of the font” – sorry but [the documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties) says differently: “The items **may** include a generic font family name […]. **In that case**, the actual font to be used will be looked up …” (emphasis mine). Furthermore, *it works* in the GUI. Anyway, I will try your proposed solutions. Thanks.

Comment: By using `fname = …` I get a RuntimeError “TrueType font is missing table” in line 776 of backend_pdf.py, in `embedTTFType3` when calling `savefig`. I’m not at home with TTF and PDF but I *have* already embedded Gill Sans in PDFs via other routes so I’m not sure what is amiss here.

Comment: You're right about using real font names as family arguments. The error message sounds like a bug. Please file it at the Sourceforge tracker, mentioning the exact font, matplotlib version and the full traceback.

Comment: OK, I’ll do that. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, I just noticed that I had only tried your `fname` solution with the `MacOSX` backend. Using the `cairo` backend, everything works fine. I’ll post a working code sample.

Answer (score 8):

Basically, @Jouni’s is the right answer but since I still had some trouble getting it to work, here’s my final solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6

import scipy
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('cairo')
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

font = fm.FontProperties(
        family = 'Gill Sans', fname = '/Library/Fonts/GillSans.ttc')

data = scipy.arange(5)
fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(data, data)
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), fontproperties = font)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), fontproperties = font)
pylab.savefig('foo.pdf')
```

Notice that the font has to be set explicitly using the `fontproperties` key. Apparently, there’s no `rc` setting for the `fname` property (at least I didn’t find it).

Giving a `family` key in the instantiation of `font` isn’t strictly necessary here, it will be ignored by the PDF backend.

*This code works with the `cairo` backend only. Using `MacOSX` won’t work.*

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to the answers above if you came here for a non-cairo backend.

The pdf-backend of matplotlib does not yet support true type font collections (saved as .ttc files). See [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3135).

The currently suggested workaround is to extract the font-of-interest from a .ttc file and save it as a .ttf file. And then use that font in the way described by Konrad Rudolph.

You can use the python-package [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) to achieve this:

```py
font = TTFont("/System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.ttc", fontNumber=0)
font.save("Helvetica-regular.ttf")
```

As far as I can see, it is not possible to make this setting "global" by passing the path to this new `.ttf` file to the [rc](https://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/users/customizing.html). If you are really desperate, you could try to extract all fonts from a `.ttc` into separate `.ttf` files, uninstall the `.ttc` and install the `ttf`s separately. To have the extracted font side-by-side with the original font from the `.ttc`, you need to change the font name with tools like [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/). I haven't tested this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are rendering the text with LaTeX, i.e., if `text.usetex` is set to `True`. Because LaTeX rendering only supports a few fonts, it largely ignores/overwrites your other fonts settings. This might be the cause.